# Match color temp, white balance of 2 JPEG

Tags: photoshop, color-management, white-balance

I have 2 jpegs of a same landscape, I want to make a panorama with it. But as they have difference tone how can I solve it using Photoshop CS6 ?
I cant open the files in Camera RAW [parent app not started or such message keeps showing], I tried adjustment -> match colour too. But it did not worked well.

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Do you have the RAW files? If you do, I highly suggest you figure out how to get Camera RAW working, because it's much easier to adjust WB on RAW files. Assuming you don't, could you check the EXIF to see what the WB settings used were?

Comment: I dont have the RAW files, and I use auto white balance always -_-

Comment: That's the worst I could have hoped for. Since it's auto, it is not even known what WB was used exactly. I guess you'd have to play around with the WB to get it to match the other one. Also: Can you confirm that the exposure settings are identical on the two?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way.  You really needed to be able to set the color balance to the same thing and with only a JPEG to go on, your ability to do that is drastically limited as color information you need to make adjustments is simply going to be missing.

Say for example that you have a pixel in the image that properly white balanced has a red value that is just shy of the maximum red value.  When you have an image that is shifted too far red, now that pixel and any with a much less red component all end up at the maximum.

When you try to adjust the white balance, there is no way to tell the difference between those pixels since the red channel was clipped by the JPEG.  You can try to color grade the image to be close (which is still going to be a largely manual process to get right) but fundamentally, chances are high that an exact match is impossible as color information is simply lost.

This is one of the main reasons why shooting RAW is extremely advisable and why, if not shooting raw, it is critical to use a fixed WB when shooting panoramic shots.

Comment: I shoot in RAW but save the JPEG only to save space

Comment: Don't do that. Sufficiently large HDDs are really cheap nowadays, and the raw contains so much more information than the JPG, e. g. you can adjust the white-balance as you wish...

Comment: @Vertigo - I tend to agree, but theoretically the extra data isn't needed after touch up.  But seeing as I can store 30mb RAW files for half a cent a piece on a redundant raid array, I tend to agree that even the minor possibility of needing it again makes it worth keeping around.  That said, I do also own over $1500 worth of HDDs.